# Autocomplete with Django, jQuery and google app engine

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

I'm new to Django and jQuery, but I have a lot of python experience. I'm basically trying to write an HTML form, with one text box for now, that as you type in it, shows you auto completion options. this will be used for finding restaurants, and I intend to use the Yelp API for that. can someone please point me out in a direction of a tutorial on how to do this - specifically with regards to the Django / HTML / jQuery rather than how to work with the Yelp API? Are there any tutorials I should read? All tutorials I have found are very basic ones that build forms from the Django data models..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quite easily accomplish this on the client-side by using the [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) widget which is part of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).
So in your case you would do something like:

```
<input id="restaurantSearch" />

<script>
$(document.ready(function() {
  $('#restaurantSearch').autocomplete({
        source: function(req, add){
          $.getJSON('http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=?', req, function(data) {  

          var restaurantSuggestions = [];

          $.each(data.businesses, function(i, business){  
            restaurantSuggestions.push(business.name);  
          });

          add(restaurantSuggestions);  
        })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tomlog's code will work on the client. But the question specifically requires google-app-engine on the server side.

To implement the server side GAE component, you'll need to search strings with regular expressions (or at least some watered down variant). GAE does not currently provide such a feature for the datastore; strings are only searchable for equality. In other words, if you have a large  datastore containing 'apple' and 'orange', you could NOT autocomplete 'app' or 'ora'.

There have been murmurs that google will be adding such features, but I wouldn't count on it soon. Therefore, if you want to autocomplete on a large data set, GAE will not yet work for you.

(you could of course build your own indexing system on top of GAE, but I'm guessing it's out of the question)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can use, to avoid re-inventing the wheel. I used it for an auto completion whithin a ForeignKey Relation:

[django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [django ajax selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/) personally but agree with the above not to reinvent the wheel